# how use something like SQL transaction in java code

Tags: java, transactions

i have an application that receive Id from Web service and store it into database if received Id for any reason like connection failed could not store in database i want to know what id was.
is there any way to do it or is there any sample code? 
i want use java language.

Answer (score 0):

Use triggers. If you use triggers than you can revoke the transactions in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a way to make sure that you don't lose the ids even if there is failure in the connection?
If so, why don't you save the last Id you receive in your code that way, you can check if there are more IDs after the last one in case of an outage, Or in your code you can make sure that the web service is reachable, and if it isn't store the IDs till the connection is restored.